# Validity of a string based on some conditions

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that checks for the validity of a string based on some conditions.

Conditions:

1. Passing a number from 0-9 as a string (ex. '1') will set valid to True.
2. Passing a number from 0-9 + * as a string (ex. '9*', '2*') will set valid to True.
3. Passing a string in brackets with a number from 0-9 + * + number from 0-9 (ex. '(9*1)', '(1*3)') will set valid to True.
4. Passing any of the above [except 2] + * + any of above [except 2] in brackets will set valid to True ex. ((9*1)*1)

anything else passed in will result in setting valid to False.

And here's what I have done:

```
CHARS = "*"
NUMBERS = "0123456789"

def validity(s):
    valid = False
    # Condition 1
    if s in NUMBERS:
        valid = True
    # Condition 2
    elif s in [c1 + CHARS for c1 in NUMBERS]:
        valid = True
    # Condition 3
    elif s in ['(' + c1 + CHARS + c2 + ')' for c1 in NUMBERS for c2 in NUMBERS]:
        valid = True
    return valid
```

I've got condition 1-3 to work properly. However where I am stuck is on condition 4.

I have a rough idea on what to do but I'm having trouble on how to implement my idea using code.

Here's my idea. If condition 4 is passed in, ex. ((9*1)*1) run validity on the string to the left of the * symbol and run validity on the string on the right of the * symbol, if both are True than the condition is True and therefore valid is set to True. If anyone can help me write down my idea in terms of code that would be really appreciated.

here are some inputs an outputs:

```
validity('1') # Condition 1
True
validity('9') # Condition 1
True
validity('10') # Doesn't satisfy any of the conditions
False
validity('1*') # Condition 2
True
validity('4*') # Condition 2
True
validity('9*') # Condition 2
True
validity('10*') # Doesn't satisfy any of the conditions
False
validity('(3*4)') # Condition 3
True
validity('(3*9)') # Condition 3
True
validity('(4*9)') # Condition 3
True
validity('(10*9)') # Doesn't satisfy any of the conditions
False
validity('(3*2)*(3*1)') # Condition 4
True
validity('(3*2)*8') # Condition 4
True
validity('(3*2)*z') # Doesn't satisfy any of the conditions
False
```

Comment: @Wooble Thank you for that, I will change those right now.

Comment: regex could probably do this in a single re.search

Comment: Arithmetic operations are generated by a context-free grammar so only one regex will be valid only if he doesn't want to continue parsing thing like: `(3*(3*2))*(3*1)`, `(3*(3*(3*2)))*(3*1)`, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will parse all the inputs you wrote using regex, but remember that arithmetic operations are generated by a context-free grammar, so you won't found a regex (only valid for regular languages) that match all existing operations (like `(3*(3*2))*(3*1)`, `(3*(3*(3*2)))*(3*1)` and so on), you will need to build different ones.

```
import re

parser1 = re.compile("[0-9]\\*?$")
parser3 = re.compile("\\([0-9]\\*[0-9]\\)$")
parser4 = re.compile("(\\([0-9]\\*[0-9]\\)|[0-9])\\*(\\([0-9]\\*[0-9]\\)|[0-9])$")

def validity(s):
    valid = False

    # Condition 1 and 2
    if parser1.match(s):
        return True
    # Condition 3
    if parser3.match(s):
        return True
    # Condition 4
    if parser4.match(s):
        return True

    return False

print validity('1') # Condition 1
print validity('9') # Condition 1
print validity('10') # Doesn't satisfy any of the conditions
print validity('1*') # Condition 2
print validity('4*') # Condition 2
print validity('9*') # Condition 2
print validity('10*') # Doesn't satisfy any of the conditions
print validity('(3*4)') # Condition 3
print validity('(3*9)') # Condition 3
print validity('(4*9)') # Condition 3
print validity('(10*9)') # Doesn't satisfy any of the conditions
print validity('(3*2)*(3*1)') # Condition 4
print validity('(3*2)*8') # Condition 4
print validity('(3*2)*z') # Doesn't satisfy any of the conditions
```

The outputs here are:

```
True
True
False
True
True
True
False
True
True
True
False
True
True
False
```

Comment: I updated my answer, now condition 4 only need one regex

Comment: why don't you write `return parser1.match(s) or parser3.match(s) or parser4.match(s)`? :P

Comment: `parserX.match(s)` doesn't return a boolean `True/False` value, they return a *Match Object* if the parsing is correct or `None` otherwise.   So if he doesn't need that anymore, it makes no sense to propagate a thing that won't be used. Moreover, in his examples he is printing the output from `validity` function, and if I return the parser result, It won't print `True` or `False`.

Comment: good point, I'm glad I asked because it wasn't obvious at all to me.